# elasticsearch get statistics on analyzed field

Tags: elasticsearch

i am trying to get statistics on analyzed string field.

i am trying to get AVG length of string field (in this example its title, and title sometimes can be empty/none).

tried:

```
GET book/_search
{
      "facets" : {
          "stat1" : {
              "statistical" : {
                  "script" : "_source.title?.length()"
              }
          }
      }
 }
```

and i get an error:

```
Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]",
   "status": 500
}
```

how can i accomplish that?

Comment: Can you try this instead: `"_source.title?.length() ?: 0"` ? The idea is to always return a value.

Comment: this returned all records. i want to get avg length..

Comment: Do you still get the `NullPointerException`? You should not.

Comment: no i dont get NullPointerException, but i dont get the requested result (AVG length of title field)

Comment: What do you get instead in your facet then? On my end I get numbers like `"_type": "statistical",
"count": 171,
"total": 650,
"min": 0,
"max": 21,
"mean": 3.801169590643275,
"sum_of_squares": 5870,
"variance": 19.8785951232858,
"std_deviation": 4.458541815805455`

Comment: sorry! you were right.. when i drill down the result i see this statistical numbers.

Comment: Good if you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you are using `facets` and not aggregations? Unless you use an Elasticsearch version that only supports facets, I recommend switching to aggregations. Facets are deprecated in 1.x and removed completely in 2.x.

And an aggregation like this one should work just fine:

```
GET /book/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "stat1": {
      "stats": {
        "script": "_source.title?.length() ?: 0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```